# Orientation camera all time wrong

Tags: android, layout, camera, orientation

I can't set the correct orientation on the preview of camera, I try all things but anything work. I want to see the preview like a camera Android app, my orientation of activity is landscape, I don't know if this is correct or wrong. In the continuous line I explain what i try:
- Change setDisplayOrientation(90) but works only if the phone is vertical, when I change the orientation is wrong again.
- I try to set portrait, but when the image is saved the orientation is wrong, and if i try to change with the exif all time orientation is 0, not works.
- I read all the ask's on SO, and anything works.

I want to kill my smartphone, but is an object and not have life. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android camera stuff is extremely frustrating, I understand that.  Make sure to read through all of the [Camera documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) and check out this code below referenced from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29):

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```

Comment: uhm, now I adjust with a portrait mode, but the preview image is a little elongated, why happens this? I don't have margins, all layout is the preview.

Comment: Sometimes you are going to have to find a previewSize with a ratio that matches your screen ratio.  I don't know why that happens, sorry.

Comment: @Uxonith What is the CameraId in this case? What should it be?

Comment: @Euridice01 It's been a long time since I posted this, but I'm assuming the cameraId is referring to the front camera or the rear.  So you should be able to pull that from the camera you are using.  Do note that the Camera class is deprecated in favor of Camera2 (requires API 21 though).